# How to remove table, tr, td tag in html with php

Tags: php, html, regex

I have a html code:

```
<table id="table1" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" width="1" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td>
    <img src="http://vnexpress.net/Files/Subject/3b/bd/ac/f9/cuongbibat.jpg" width="330" height="441" border="1" alt="C&#432;&#7901;ng">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="Image">Everything
   </td>
  </tr>
</table>
 <table id="table2" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" width="1" align="center">
      <tr>
        <td>
        Someone
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="Image">Everything
       </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

I have 2 table, i want to remove all tag: table, tr, td if table have img tag(table 1).
I need to get result like :

```
     <img src="http://vnexpress.net/Files/Subject/3b/bd/ac/f9/cuongbibat.jpg" width="330" height="441" border="1" alt="C&#432;&#7901;ng">
        Everything


     <table id="table2" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" width="1" align="center">
          <tr>
            <td>
            Someone
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="text">Everything
           </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
```

Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried echoing a comment? `<?='<!--'?>` & `<?='-->'?>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory, it's possible to do this with a single highly complex regexp. It's always easier to do the search-and-replace on separate steps: search for the outer container first, then work on what it contains.

```
<?php 

header("Content-type: text/plain");

$html = '<table id="table1" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" width="1" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td>
    <img src="http://vnexpress.net/Files/Subject/3b/bd/ac/f9/cuongbibat.jpg" width="330" height="441" border="1" alt="C&#432;&#7901;ng">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="Image">Everything
   </td>
  </tr>
</table>
 <table id="table2" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" width="1" align="center">
      <tr>
        <td>
        Someone
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="Image">Everything
       </td>
      </tr>
    </table> ';


$html = preg_replace_callback('/<table\b[^>]*>.*?<\/table>/si', 'removeTableIfImg', $html);

function removeTableIfImg($matches) {
    $table = $matches[0];
    return preg_match('/<img\b[^>]*>/i', $table, $img) 
         ? preg_replace('/<\/?(?:table|td|tr)\b[^>]*>\s*/i', '', $table)
         : $table;
}
echo $html;

?>
```

The first pattern finds the tables. The second pattern (in the callback) checks if there's an image tag. The third removes the table, td, and tr tags.

Comment: Thank you but nothing happen when use this.  $s="my html code";

              $s = preg_replace_callback('/<table\b[^>]*>.*?<\/table>/si', 'removeTableIfImg', $s);

function removeTableIfImg($matches) {
    $table = $matches[0];
    return preg_match('/<img\b[^>]*>/i', $table, $img) 
         ? preg_replace('/<\/?(?:table|td|tr)\b[^>]*>[\s+]*/', '', $table)
         : $table;
}
var_dump($s);die();                                                         it print all with 2 table tag:(

Comment: I just tried it and it works. The last expression probably should be case insensitive, btw.

Comment: i don't know why my code didn't work :(. Can you give me your code?

Answer (score 4):

[HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) can be used to strip either all tags or a certain set of tags from a document. It's the go-to solution for basically any HTML tag stripping in PHP - **don't ever use regexes for this** or the sun will burn out and we will all freeze to death in the suffocating darkness.

Try something like:

```
$config->set('HTML.Allowed', 'img');
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
$output = $filter->purify($YOUR_HTML);
```

You'll need to add a `$config->set('HTML.Allowed', 'TAGNAME');` line for every tag you don't want to get scrubbed away, but it's a price worth paying for the continued lifegiving warmth of the day-star. And also not leaving your site open to XSS attacks and content-eating glitches, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Check out:
http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Let's you find tags on an HTML page with selectors just like jQuery and extract contents from HTML in a single line.

Answer (score 0):

i needed something like this.
here is my solution:
`(<\/?tr.*?>)|(<\/?td.*?>)|(<\/?table.*?>)`

this regex will select all tr td and table tags not greedy.

you can see it in action here:

http://regexr.com/3fslh

Answer (score -2):

As sudowned said do not use regex for this, it will drive you crazy. Usually searching for libs   consumes the same amount of time than writing your own small parser for this. I did this several times in different languages. You learn a lot and you often can reuse the code :-)

since you are not interested in attributes, this should be quite easy. loop the entry site char by char. Check out this java code, its one of my earlier, smaller approach to sanitize html:

```
public static String sanatize(String body, String[] whiteList, String tagSeperator, String seperate) {
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder tag = new StringBuilder();

    boolean quoteOpen = false;
    boolean tagOpen = false;
    for(int i=0;i<body.length();i++) {
        char c = body.charAt(i);
        if(i<body.length()-1 && c == '<'  && !quoteOpen && body.charAt(i+1) != '!') {
            tagOpen = true;
            tag.append(c);
        } else if(c == '>'  && !quoteOpen && tagOpen) {
            tag.append(c);

            for (String tagName : whiteList) {
                String stag = tag.toString().toLowerCase();
                if (stag.startsWith("</"+tagName+" ") || stag.startsWith("</"+tagName+">") || stag.startsWith("<"+tagName+" ") || stag.startsWith("<"+tagName+">")) {
                    out.append(tag);
                } else if (stag.startsWith("</") && tagSeperator != null) {
                    if (seperate.length()>2) {
                        if (seperate.contains("," + stag.replaceAll("[</]+(\\w+)[\\s>].*", "$1") + ",")) {
                            out.append(tagSeperator);
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (!out.toString().endsWith(tagSeperator)) {
                            out.append(tagSeperator);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            tag = new StringBuilder(); 
            tagOpen = false;
        } else if (c == '"' && !quoteOpen) {
            quoteOpen = true;
            if (tagOpen)
                tag.append(c);
            else 
                out.append(c);
        } else if (i>1 && c == '"' && quoteOpen && body.charAt(i-1) != '\\' ) {
            quoteOpen = false;
            if (tagOpen)
                tag.append(c);
            else 
                out.append(c);
        } else {
            if (tagOpen)
                tag.append(c);
            else 
                out.append(c);
        }
    }

    return out.toString();
}
```

You can ignore separator and separate, I used this to sanitise tags and convert to csv

Comment: This is Java. The question is about php.

Comment: yes its java, but a programmer should be able to translate the concept from java to php

Comment: The concept is wrong. Search and replace is almost as wrong as regexes in the context of DOM manipulation. This is like helping the OP fix his car by explaining how to light it on fire. In Klingon.